# Number Theory-Find all natural numbers n such that

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Find all positive integers n, such that
\begin{equation}
22^n+8^n-11^n-3^n \equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ 209)
\end{equation}
My attempt so far:
\begin{equation}
11^n(2^n-1)\equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ 209)  \Leftrightarrow\ (2^n-1)\equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ 19)
\end{equation}
But from Euler theorem \begin{equation} \Rightarrow\ 2^{18}\equiv 1\ (\textrm{mod}\ 19) \Rightarrow\ 2^{180}\equiv 1\ (\textrm{mod}\ 19).
\end{equation}
In the same fashion we get that \begin{equation}
8^{180}-3^{180}\equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ 209).
\end{equation}
Finally, \begin{equation} \Rightarrow\ 11^{180}(2^{180}-1)+8^{180}-3^{180}\equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ 209).
\end{equation}
But maybe there are even more solutions, so how can I find them?

Comment: Try to think of a more concise title to your questions. You are trying to determine the cardinality of a subset of the natural numbers, is it finite or infinite? might be a good preliminary question that leads to the final answer you are after here.

Comment: @AdamL If you say so

Comment: SPecial case of the general methoids explained in the linked dupes (and their links).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you are partitioning the left side, as you are eliminating solutions. All we want is the expression to be equivalent to $0$ mod $11$ and mod $19$.

For mod $11$, we have $$8^n\equiv3^n\bmod{11}\to(-3)^n\equiv3^n\bmod{11}$$So the solutions to this mod equation are when $n$ is even.

For mod $19$, we have $$3^n+8^n-11^n-3^n\equiv0\bmod{19}\to8^n\equiv(-8)^n\bmod{19}$$Which again is true for all even $n$ (and only for even $n$).

So, the system is true for any even $n$.

Comment: lease strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.

Comment: @BillDubuque I didn't know this was a FAQ. OP also showed effort, so I decided to answer.